# Height of the Inner Content doesn't get changed when changing the container height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the 3rd element to take the place of the element second when clicked on the button, I know I can use `.remove()` to remove that specific block of code, but it will not gonna transition, so I want the third element to take place of the second with transition instead of direct getting there. How can I do that? I try to do the example but changing the height of the 2nd container, but the inner Content didn't change and it also didn't transition even though I have set the transition on the height

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const all = document.querySelectorAll('.cont');
  all[1].classList.add('changeheight');
})
```

```css
.changeheight {
  height: 0px;
  transition: height 250ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont"><h1>Hello 1</h1></div>
<div class="cont"><h1>Hello 2</h1></div>
<div class="cont"><h1>Hello 3</h1></div>
<div class="cont"><h1>Hello 4</h1></div>


<button id="btn">
  Click
</button>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the scale property to make it disappear?

Comment: You need to use ```max-height``` and add ```overflow: hidden```.

Comment: @prettyInPink can you please show an example

Comment: @prettyInPink I didn't have any specific height and I just want to transition the appearence that the below element is taking its place instead of totally removing it

Answer (score 0):

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const all = document.querySelectorAll('.cont');
  all[1].classList.add('changeheight');
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cont {
  height: 50px;
}

.changeheight {
  height: 0px;
  transition: height 350ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <h1>Hello 1</h1>
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <h1>Hello 2</h1>
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <h1>Hello 3</h1>
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <h1>Hello 4</h1>
</div>


<button id="btn">
        Click
    </button>
```

Comment: Nothing happen, even the height didn't change

Comment: run above snippet here

Comment: what if I don't have any specific height for that?

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden` to changeHeight class and take some idea from [@CyrusKabir answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72283551/19117401)

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const all = document.querySelectorAll('.cont');
  all[1].classList.add('changeheight');
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cont {
  height: 50px;
}

.changeheight {
  height: 0px;
  transition: height 550ms ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <h1>Hello 1</h1>
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <h1>Hello 2</h1>
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <h1>Hello 3</h1>
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <h1>Hello 4</h1>
</div>


<button id="btn">
        Click
    </button>
```

Comment: but no transition?

Comment: @Ernie I just add some line in code, maybe it will work like you want!